# How to calculate count of LP tokens

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, tokens, metamask, cryptoeconomics

I'd like to know how to get a count of LP tokens from assets.

Here is an example.
I have made a token of the name "ABC".
I'd like to provide liquidity in Pancakeswap and make ABC-BNB pair.
If I provide 1000 ABCs and 10 BNBs, how many CAKE-LP tokens do I get?
Thanks for your kind answers.